# Indirectly computing radii of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, alternative-proof

Suppose we're asked to find the radius of convergence of a power/Taylor series for some function. Is there a way to know or guess the radius of convergence without computing the $f^{(n)}(0)$'s (or $f^{(n)}(a)$'s)? The one I encountered was some rational function that was something like $$f(x) = \frac{1+x^3}{x-2}$$

I used the ratio test to get

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{f^{(n+1)}(0)}{f^{(n)}(0)}||\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}||\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^n}|$$

$$= |\frac{f^{(n+1)}(0)}{f^{(n)}(0)}| \frac{1}{n+1} |x|$$

I guessed the limit would be zero for any $x$ and hence the radius is infinite. Since $f(x)$ isn't defined at $x=2$, [I'm guessing I was wrong](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Bx%5E3)%2F(x-2),%20maclaurin%20series). Even if I remembered the function wrong, I believe the denominator wasn't strictly nonzero.

I'm not sure the shortest way to go about this is to compute the first few $f^{(n)}(0)$'s and then guess a pattern. Is there perhaps some kind of theorem for radii of convergence, $f^{(n)}(0)$'s or $\frac{f^{(n+1)}(0)}{f^{(n)}(0)}$'s for certain functions (e.g. rational, continuous on its domain, etc)?

P.S. You may use complex analysis, but I haven't taken that yet.

Comment: The radius of convergence of the Taylor series of an analytic function is the distance to the nearest singularity. To see why, and for a proof, look at complex analysis.

Comment: @DanielFischer oh, thanks! So if the rational function happened to have strictly nonzero denominator, I guessed right (infinite radius) ?

Comment: If a rational function has strictly nonzero denominator, the denominator is constant. Hence it's a polynomial. When dealing with radii of convergence, you have to think of complex arguments, since the behaviour of the series on the real domain and the radius of convergence of the Taylor series have no obvious connection.

Comment: @DanielFischer On your first comment, how do you define a singularity in this generality?

Comment: @DanielFischer But what if you don't consider complex numbers?

Comment: @zhw. Any point at which the function is not analytic. Well, since $f$ might be defined on an unnaturally small domain, we have to consider the analytic continuations to deal with the fully general case, and then it becomes a little cumbersome to state (and while the condition remains true, it may not be helpful then). But for rational functions and some other easy cases, it's far easier to see where poles, branchpoints, isolated essential singularities are than to determine the derivatives.

Comment: @BCLC If you don't want to consider complex numbers, you have to do it the hard way and find the derivatives, as far as I know, since the radius of convergence has no direct connection to the behaviour on the real domain. Look at $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Its Taylor series about $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ has radius of convergence $\sqrt{x_0^2 + 1}$. Huh, why, how does that come? It's obvious if you look at complex arguments, since the function has poles at $i$ and $-i$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks! ^-^ Post as answer?

Comment: @DanielFischer Pretty much done self-studying complex analysis now. Posted an answer without complex analysis. I might be misunderstanding my own question, but if I understand right, I think I was over thinking. I answered without complex analysis. Where did I go wrong, if anywhere, in my answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait, was I overthinking?

$$f(x) = \frac{1+x^3}{x-2} = \frac{1+x^3}{1}\frac{1}{x-2}$$

$$= \frac{1+x^3}{1}\frac{-1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac x 2)^k$$

for $|x|<2$

Alternatively,

$$= \frac{1+x^3}{1}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac 2 x)^k$$

for $|x|>2$

In either case, radius = 2.